# How can I access camera and take photos within my R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, camera

I am willing to make my Shiny App accessing the camera and take photos every 5 seconds in the background. I do not want to see the photos on the screen. I just want them to be stored. I looked into web and found some packages that people are talking about like Rvision, opencv, etc. but I did not find them helpful for my job! Please let me know if there is a way at all to do this in R.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if this were [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (it is not), perhaps you can frame it in a way that doesn't sound like it's silently stalking whomever happens to be in front of the computer. Or worse, if you are intending the shiny app to gain access through a remote user's browser and take pictures using their camera.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, you are right. The way it reads, it seems that I am trying to silently collect the photos of the user of the App. let me explain in more details. I am trying to mount a GoPro (or any other camera) to a bicycle and collect imagery of bike trails. I need to be able to select between cameras connected to the computer (GoPro or default camera). The intention is to have a leaflet map in front of the user and the location of each collected image to be shown as a dot on the map.

Comment: *"take photos every 5 seconds"* has nothing to do with *"shown as a dot on the map"*.

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean. The thing is that I am fine with the leaflet part and showing the location of the photos on the map. However, the part I am struggling with is taking photos continuously. I've found similar topics in stack overflow for Python. I am not sure if it is even doable within R. I tried the approach explained here (https://swarm-lab.github.io/Rvision/) but it did not work for me. was wondering if there is any package/tool available that I can use.

Comment: I think I see where you are going with this. Some issues: first, your question is really under-stating the problem and if it is to stay open then you really need to [edit] it and add the details that have come out in comments. Included in this would be (IIUC) the fact that you have a gopro attached to a computer/tablet on a bicycle, and you want the shiny app to be able (user-permitted) to access the camera(s) and record pictures (user-permitted).

Comment: Second, it is expressly off-topic (see my first link) to ask for us to recommend a software package, SO is not intended to be a software-recommendation forum (there's https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, though less-frequented than SO). I am leaning towards being more accommodating with this, others may not be, but I tend to be more lenient with questions that have a clear vision, explain it well, and spark my curiosity. With all of those details, I find your case interesting, but it's out of my expertise, I don't know R/vision enough to help.

Comment: Either way, there are currently 2 votes to close, if a 3rd comes your question will be closed. This is not abnormal, especially for those new to SO. I suggest you [edit] the question to fill it out, and at least get things started. Please continue to try to use SO, even if this one question doesn't work perfectly; asking questions on SO in a way that has a high chance of getting actionable answers is not always intuitive and is a learned skill.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/webcam-easy/dist/webcam-easy.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "shinyWebcam.js")
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 3, 
      actionButton("run", "Take photos", class = "btn-block btn-primary"),
      br(),
      actionButton("stop", "Stop webcam", class = "btn-block btn-warning")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 9,
      tags$video(
        id = "webcam", autoplay = "", playsinline = "", width="640", height="480"
      ),
      tags$canvas(id = "canvas", class = "d-none")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

File **shinyWebcam.js**, to put in the **www** subfolder of the shiny app:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const webcamElement = document.getElementById("webcam");
  const canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const webcam = new Webcam(webcamElement, "user", canvasElement);
  webcam
    .start()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("webcam started");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  let interval;
  let i = 0;
  $("#run").on("click", function () {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      const picture = webcam.snap();
      i++;
      const j = i.toString().padStart(5, "0");
      const filename = "pic" + j;
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.append(a);
      a.download = filename;
      a.href = picture;
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    }, 5000);
  });
  $("#stop").on("click", function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    webcam.stop();
  });
});
```

Perhaps your browser asks you to choose a folder for a download; if so, you have to disable this option in your browser settings.