# Is it possible to use R for creating a mobile app that needs to be able to use the phones camera?

Tags: r, shiny

This is my first post.
I have some experience in developing Shiny web apps and I want to do a project where the user can take a picture with their phone, write a short summary of the image and then upload it so that it is accessible to other users who can also upload. I am wondering if this is feasible in R or should I learn another language? If so, which do you recommend and where should I start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did it for a laptop, I don't know whether it works for a phone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72058675/1100107

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your project does not seem to make use of any strong property of the R language and its ecosystem (vectorization, advanced statistics, grammar of graphics, functional programming).
Thus, it does not seem to be a good fit here.
Shiny is just a wrapper around JavaScript to make websites hosted on a computer server which can be accessed by any device using a browser. There is [shinywebcam](https://github.com/Emelieh21/shinywebcam), which might work on mobile browsers, but the calculation is done on the hosting server and not the phone itself, so it's not an app traditionally.